deploy wso2 apim 4.3 microk8s error publisher
im using wso2 api manager 4.3 in  a microk8s using the single node pattern, i replace the image in the values config, as way a the domain.
   dockerRegistry: "docker.io"
  imageName: "wso2/wso2am"
  imageTag: "4.3.0"
  imagePullPolicy: Always

Also replace the storage class
persistentRuntimeArtifacts:    
storageClass: &storage_class"microk8s-hostpath"

And the ingress
 ingress:
        management:
          enabled: true
          hostname: "paul-inspiron-5570.local"
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
        gateway:
          enabled: true
          # Hostname for Gateway profile
          hostname: "gateway.paul-inspiron-5570.local"
          # Annotations for the API Manager Gateway service Ingress
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        websub:
          enabled: true
          hostname: "websub.paul-inspiron-5570.local"
          # Annotations for the API Manager WebSub service Ingress
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        websocket:
          enabled: true
          hostname: "websocket.paul-inspiron-5570.local"
          # Annotations for the API Manager WebSocket service Ingress
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

how ever when I login to the publisher endpoint after login the homepage is not displaying any options just appear
Let’s get started !
Choose your option to create an API
Im running using this command:
   microk8s helm3 install my-apim am-single --version 4.3.0 --namespace myapim --dependency-update  --create-namespace

the logs says:
[2024-09-23 02:08:12,762] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Failed to get Environments in tenant domain: carbon.super
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'TYPE' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.65.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at jdk.proxy7.$Proxy55.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllEnvironments_aroundBody682(ApiMgtDAO.java:14324) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllEnvironments(ApiMgtDAO.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getEnvironments_aroundBody644(APIUtil.java:7839) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getEnvironments(APIUtil.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common.mappings.SettingsMappingUtil.fromSettingstoDTO(SettingsMappingUtil.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.SettingsApiServiceImpl.getSettings(SettingsApiServiceImpl.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.SettingsApi.getSettings(SettingsApi.java:53) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[?:?]
[2024-09-23 02:08:12,762] ERROR - SettingsApiServiceImpl Error while retrieving Publisher Settings
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to get Environments in tenant domain: carbon.super
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.handleException_aroundBody334(ApiMgtDAO.java:7366) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.handleException(ApiMgtDAO.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllEnvironments_aroundBody682(ApiMgtDAO.java:14349) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllEnvironments(ApiMgtDAO.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getEnvironments_aroundBody644(APIUtil.java:7839) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getEnvironments(APIUtil.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common.mappings.SettingsMappingUtil.fromSettingstoDTO(SettingsMappingUtil.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common_9.29.120.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.SettingsApiServiceImpl.getSettings(SettingsApiServiceImpl.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.SettingsApi.getSettings(SettingsApi.java:53) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.8.41.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.9.26.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.85.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'TYPE' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.65.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at jdk.proxy7.$Proxy55.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllEnvironments_aroundBody682(ApiMgtDAO.java:14324) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.29.120.jar:?]
    ... 60 more

Please help me and thanks a lot
Greetings

How did you create the databases?

i don't use any step further the steps  in the helm install command, did i need to exeute an additional step , i suppose the helm create the mysql pod and the db, there is another step to do ?
